# Array of jquery DataTables objects gives type errors

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm dynamically generating tables and every time I generate one, I create a corresponding DataTable object, which I store in an array.

```js
tables1 = {};
```

I create the objects and get the values like so (posterized for easy viewing):

```js
categoryIds.each( function ( value, index ) {
     tables1[value]=jQuery('#tbl' + category_id).DataTable();
});

jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'get',
    }).done(function(data) {
        object = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        object.each(function(value, index) {
            tables1[value.catid].row.add([value.id, value.title]);
        });

        categoryIds.each( function ( value, index ) {
            tables1[value].draw();
            //typeerror here
        }
});
```

The above gives me a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` error, but works if I surround it with try catches.

Once I've created the tables and want to wipe them, even this simple function is giving me an typeerror:

```js
jQuery.each(tables1, function ( index, value) {
    tables1[index].clear().draw();
} );
```

I'm using DataTables 1.10, and googling this error seems to pop up mostly when dealing with ajax data sources, which I'm not using.

Comment: `tableprds1` is not defined - or defined where ...? Seems to be a simple typo.

Comment: Edited, that should be tables1.

Comment: Does  `value.clear().draw()`  / `value.draw()` work? (it should work) - if the above code is used `value` should hold the `dtInstance`.  The code is correct as it is, so something is missing.